# java public static final object

Tags: java, static, final

following code, containing file is [here](https://github.com/AurelienRibon/universal-tween-engine/blob/master/java/api/src/aurelienribon/tweenengine/equations/Quart.java)

```
public abstract class Quart extends TweenEquation {
    public static final Quart IN = new Quart() {
        @Override
        public final float compute(float t) {
        return t*t*t*t;
    }
    ...
```

if i call Quart.IN.compute(0.5f) somewhere in my running application (e.g. in a render() function that is called 60 times per second), does this create a new Quart on every call, or is it just allocated once?

it would make sense, right?

thanks,
cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, a final variable can only be assigned once. And static fields of a class are initialized when the class is loaded. So obviously, the `IN` Quart instance is created just once.

Answer (score 0):

> is it just allocated once

Yes, you're calling the `compute` method always on the same single object.

Answer (score 0):

Just once. The static field IN is initialized during the first access to the class Quart.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check it's created only once by writing output when an instance of Quart is created:

```
public abstract class Quart extends TweenEquation {
    public static final Quart IN = new Quart() {

        { System.out.println("created"); }

        @Override
        public final float compute(float t) {
            return t*t*t*t;
        }
    ...
```